# Failed installing Ubuntu package

Tags: package-management, system-installation, software-installation

I can't install the any package on ubuntu. For example, `sudo apt install git` I've got this issue.

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package 'linux-modules-5.4.0-48-generic' is missing final newline
Error: Timeout was reached
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not an expert but "files list file for package 'linux-modules-5.4.0-48-generic' is missing final newline" looks like there is something wrong with the repository.

Comment: How I can fix? Can you help me, please?

Comment: If my guess is right  (I hope not) that there is something rotten in the repository, you can't do anything but pray. OR become an expert, join the project and fix it.

Comment: Let's see your terminal history. Paste this in terminal: `history > history.txt` and press Enter. Now go to Files app and in Home you'll see a new file named 'history.txt'. Copy the contents of the file and paste it in a pastebin and share the link.